# Different layout for exercise, header, etc

Tags: indentation

1. I want to set different layouts in a book, say the bodywidth (4in) + maginalwidth (2in) and 'exercise part' (6in) at the end of each section such as a typical calculus book.
   I am using `\minipage[h]{6in}` for the 'exercise part' right now, which is not good when a part of 'exercise' needs to be carried over to the next page.
2. I want the header (and footer) width to be 6in, even the bodywidth is 4in.
   Is anyway to do that??

Comment: You are missing the 'exercises' tag

Answer (score 2):

You can use the `package` [geometry](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/geometry) with the command `\newgeometry`. For more details see the [documentation](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/geometry/geometry.pdf).

Comment: The OP mentions `minipage`s and carrying over text parts to the next page, so it seems he/she wants to change the "margins" for *parts* of a page. For this, the `geometry` package is not appropriate.

Comment: @lockstep: The question is very old and the OP gave no response. I think we should simple ignore this question.

Comment: I stumbled upon the question in the process of sorting out the [tag:margins] and [tag:indentation] tags.

Answer (score 1):

To change the "margins" (better: the indentation) for text blocks in the middle of a page, use the [changepage](http://ctan.org/pkg/changepage) package, the [fullwidth](http://ctan.org/pkg/fullwidth) package or the `addmargin` environment of the [KOMA-Script](http://ctan.org/pkg/koma-script) classes resp. the `scrextend` package which is included in `KOMA-Script`.